# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{i}^{3^n}}{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I’m given a problem for homework and I want to as how to solve it:

> does the following sum converge? $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{i}^{3^n}}{n}$$

It converges since ${i}^{3^n} $ is $-i, \space i, \space -i, \space i, \space -i, \space ...$ and it is $i (-1)^n$. So our given sum is equivalent to the sum $$i \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ (-1)^n}{n} $$. But how can I prove without using wolfram alpha that ${i}^{3^n} \equiv i (-1)^n$ ?

Comment: (1) It _doesn't_ converge absolutely; what is the absolute value of $i^{3^n}/n$? (2) You can either argue by induction (note that $i^{3^{n+1}}=\left(i^{3^n}\right)^3$) or by noting that the value of $i^k$ is only dependent on $k\bmod 4$.

Comment: $3= -1\mod 4$ and $i^4=1$. The series *does not* converge *absolutely*.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki sorry my bad, I meant that it indeed converges hahaha

Comment: Hint: $(i)$ Use [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) , $(ii)$ Consider modulus of your series and $(iii)$ Conclude by [Comparison Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof by induction. The base case $n=1$ is clear. Now suppose that the claim holds for all positive integers less than or equal to $n$. Then 
$$
i^{3^{n+1}}=(i^{3^{n}})^3\stackrel{\text{IH}}{=}(i(-1)^n)^3=-i(-1)^{3n}=i(-1)^{3n+1}=i(-1)^{n+1}
$$
since $3n+1\equiv n+1$ modulo $2$, where $\text{IH}$ refers to induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $n\geq 0$, 
$$
i^n=\begin{cases} 1&n\cong0\mod4\\
i&n\cong1\mod4 \\
-1&n\cong2\mod4 \\
-i&n\cong3\mod4\\
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
3^n\cong(-1)^n\mod 4
$$
so your sum converges since the alternating harmonic series converges.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i<sup>4k+a</sup> = i<sup>a</sup>. That is, i<sup>n</sup> = i<sup>n mod 4</sup>. But note that mod 4, 3 = -1. So i<sup>3<sup>n</sup></sup> = i<sup>(-1)<sup>n</sup></sup> = i(i<sup>(-1)<sup>n</sup>-1</sup>). Since (-1)<sup>n</sup> = (-1)<sup>p</sup> where p = n mod 2, we can write this as i(i<sup>(-1)<sup>p</sup>-1</sup>). If p = 0, then i<sup>(-1)<sup>p</sup>-1</sup> is 1, and if p = 1, this is -1.